# How to set Autoclick on all the buttons of a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using Jquery and Ajax for performing the action, I need after loading complete page, a code click on the every button automatically.

I used the following javascript code for click all the buttons in the end of my page. but it is not working.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementByClassName('sub').click();
</script>
```

Structure of my Page code

```
[JQuery]
[PHP]
[HTML]
[Javascript]
```

I set all the buttons type as "BUTTON", When I set

> type="submit"

The Autoclick code only work on the first button, but with the "button" type it is not working with any of them.

If I click manually on that buttons they are working properly.

Please give any suggestion. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre using the wrong function. Elements is plural in that method.

`document.getElementsByClassName('sub');`

Additionally, calling click on this NodeList will not work. You need to loop through and call the event on each index.

Also, you say you're using jQuery. To ensure your call happens after DOM ready, wrap your JS with $().ready().

Last, use the tools you've provided yourself, in this case jQuery, and select your element that way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sub").click()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can trigger the click like

```
$( ".sub" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you retrieve a NodeList(as pointed out in the comments) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var butEl = document.getElementsByClassName('sub'),
        count = butEl.length;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
        butEl[i].click();
    }
});
```

Also is `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: FYI, it is not an array. It is a NodeList. It is a subtle but significant difference. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to click on multiple different form submit buttons, it makes sense that the browser will POST for only one of them - one page can't simultaneously navigate to multiple different URLs.

Similarly, when you change `type` to `button`, none of the forms will be submitted, even though you're clicking on the buttons.

If you know what you're doing, you could always add `submit` event handlers to all of your forms, and submit them via ajax requests instead - which should allow multiple of them to be processed. Note you may need to work out some extra logic for displaying success/failure for each form to the user since the browser won't navigate you to any of the existing "submitted" pages.

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            // Add logic here for handling success for each form, if required
        },
        error: function(xhr, err) {
            // Add logic here for handling errors for each form, if required
        }
    });
    return false; // To stop the browser processing this form
});
```

With this method, your first attempt with `type="submit"` buttons should work - however I would encourage you to be as specific as possible with your element selectors for both the forms and the buttons you're trying to target.